# CS-Script is busy despite not running anything else?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, cs-script, vscode-code-runner

I'm running Visual Studio and CSScript. My program is extremely simple.

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
class Hello 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

However, when I try to run it, the error message shows:

```
CS-Script is busy.
```

Edit: @TheGeneral mentioned that I forgot to include how I was running the program, which is a very valid concern. I am running the program using coderunner in Visual Studio.

Comment: you are running a console app from a cs-script in a console app? im not sure this will work, try removing `Console.ReadKey();` also how are you running this, you have not shown any code apart from the script

Comment: Fixed it. Is this better?

Comment: Does it work if you comment out `Console.ReadKey();`?

Comment: I restarted my computer and it seemed to fix the issue. next time it arises I will try to comment it out and see if this is the solution.